Why is the function $x\mapsto |x|^a$ ($a\in ]0,2]$) negative definite?
I'm studying negative definite functions from the book C. Berg, and G. Forst, Potential Theory on Locally Compact Abelian Groups (Springer Berlin Heidelberg, Berlin, Heidelberg, 1975). In this book, a negative definite function is $f:\widehat{G}\to\mathbb{C}$ if for all natural numbers $n$ and all $n$-tuples $(\gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_n)$ of elements from $\widehat{G}$, the $n\times n$ matrix
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}(f(\gamma_i)-\overline{f(\gamma_j)}-f(x_i-x_j)c_i \overline{c_j}\geq 0
\end{align}
for any $n$-tuple $(c_1,\ldots, c_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$.
In the same book, in an example, is affirmated that the function $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto |x|^a$ is negative definite for $a\in ]0,2]$.
Question 1. Why is $x\mapsto |x|^a$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ negative definite?
Question 2. If $f$ is a negative definite function then $f$ is polynomially bounded?
Thanks.

Do you know Bochner's theorem ?
